# как залинковать блиблиотеку в CMake?

Tags: mingw, cmake

пишу клиент сервер на С, необходимо подключить библиотеку Ws2_32.lib к проэкту,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(os3 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
add_executable(os3 main.c)
target_link_libraries (os3 find_library(WS2_32.LIB))
```

воспользовался этой функцией, выдает такие ошибки:

```
    C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-7~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfind_library
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-7~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l(
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-7~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l)
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\os3.dir\build.make:96: os3.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/os3.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/os3.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: os3] Error 2
```

использую MinGw
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать `find_package`

```
find_package(имя_пакета REQUIRED)
```